configuration of Synthetic Monitors
I'm trying to fetch the configuration of Synthetic Monitors created over ELK cloud, how i can achieve that !
I have tried postman and curl command but not getting the desired result but still not able to fetch that.
From the ELK development tool, I tried to fetch the result but still no luck !
